# permalink not showing correctly using wp_insert_post and post_name

Tags: permalinks, slug, wp-insert-post

So I am using `wp_insert_post()` to create new posts dynamically.

But I am trying to achieve the permalink structure to Parent/Child page as:
Parent/Child/GChild or mydomain/MYTitle/1/1/ (yes I want the titles of the child and gchild post/permalink to be numbers!).

Now I understand to change the permalink I have to add the arg: `'post_name' => 'something',`.

Now I have wrote the entire script to loop through and create all posts and it's children, and that all works fine.

The problem that I am having is that the post_name is not forcing the title as the post_name, thus throwing off my permalink structure.

Works fine if the children post_name are letters, but modifies the `post_name` if I use numbers as the post_name (1 turns into 1-2).

The result I want should look like:

`mydomain/MYTitle/1/1/` and NOT `mydomain/MYTitle/1-2/1-2/`

My loop code looks like:

```
foreach( ... ):

$parent_args = array(
      'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($post_title),
      'post_name' => wp_unique_post_slug($post_title),
);    
$parent_post_id = wp_insert_post( $parent_args ); 

$i = 1;
foreach( ... ):

$child_args = array(
      'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($i),
      'post_name' => wp_unique_post_slug($i),
      'post_parent'  => $parent_post_id, 
);    
$child_post_id = wp_insert_post( $child_args );

$i++;

endforeach; //child


endforeach;//parent
```

Does anyone know how to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH!

https://permalinkmanager.pro/docs/tutorials/how-to-remove-numbers-2-3-appended-to-the-permalinks/

So the automatic slug creation of -2, -3, ..etc is done by core in order to make slugs unique. But I knew there was a way to change the permalink and not the slug. I just couldn't find code anywhere to do this so I resorted to using this premium plugin.

```
global $permalink_manager_uris;
foreach( ... ):

$parent_args = array(
      'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($post_title),
      'post_name' => wp_unique_post_slug($post_title),
);    
$parent_post_id = wp_insert_post( $parent_args ); 

// Declare the custom URI for parent post
$permalink_manager_uris[$parent_post_id] = sanitize($post_title);

$i = 1;
foreach( ... ):

$child_args = array(
      'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($i),
      'post_name' => wp_unique_post_slug($i),
      'post_parent'  => $parent_post_id, 
);    
$child_post_id = wp_insert_post( $child_args );

// Declare the custom URI for child post
$permalink_manager_uris[$child_post_id] = sanitize($post_title).'/'.$i;

$i++;

endforeach; //child


endforeach;//parent

update_option('permalink-manager-uris', $permalink_manager_uris);
```